# Android MapView blank on tab switch

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs

I've been sitting with this problem for quite a while now. I have 4 tabs (ViewPager) the 2nd tab contains a MapView. When I navigate to the map tab from the 1st or 3rd tab the map shows fine, it zooms into my location and shows markers, but as soon as I navigate to the map tab from the 4th tab it doesn't Set Up. It just shows a blank map with no markers or no zooming. When I open another activity from the tabs and return back to the map it also doesn't set up the map.

Any help will be appreciated since this problem has been bugging me for weeks:

**Code:**

***MapsAtivity.java***

```
public class MapsActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private static View view;
static LatLng p1 = null;
private static GoogleMap mMap;
private static String EVENT_LOC_URL = "";
public static Marker me;
public static String names[];
View v;
static Context ctx;
MapView mapView;

public static MapsActivity newInstance(int page, String title) {
    MapsActivity mapsActivity = new MapsActivity();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    mapsActivity.setArguments(args);
    return mapsActivity;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
    ctx = getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ctx = getActivity();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    EVENT_LOC_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.server) + "eventLocations.php";
    FloatingActionButton mLocate = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.locateme);
    mLocate.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    if (mMap != null)
        setUpMap();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null)
            setUpMap();
    }
}

/***** Sets up the map if it is possible to do so *****/
public void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = mapView.getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null)
            setUpMap();
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    getLongLat gl = new getLongLat(ctx);
    showMyLoc(gl.getLatitude(), gl.getLongitude(), 16);
    me = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(gl.getLatitude(), gl.getLongitude()))
            .title("Current Location")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.locateme:
            doLocate();
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();

    // Remove the map fragment to prevent errors on the next load
    if(mMap != null){
        try {
        Fragment mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
            getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .remove(mapFragment)
                    .commit();
            mMap = null;
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
}

public void doLocate(){
    me.remove();
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    getLongLat gl = new getLongLat(ctx);
    showMyLoc(gl.getLatitude(), gl.getLongitude(), 16);
    me = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(gl.getLatitude(), gl.getLongitude()))
            .title("Current Location")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

}

private static void showMyLoc(double latitude, double longitude, int i) {
    /////----------------------------------Zooming camera to position user-----------------
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
    try {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 800));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                .zoom(i)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(0)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(90)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("Error: ", ex.toString());
        Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_loading_location), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

There's no logcat errors or anything I just receive a empty map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by setting the **offscreenpagelimit** and adding the following code to the **onDestroyView** method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

In the **MainActivity.java** is where the **ViewPager** is set up. I added the following code:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(11);
```